# Spring Data JPA Read Thread Safe using multithreading

Tags: sql-server, database, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

We have a table in SQL server which is having some set of records. We have a requirement to read a record and call some external service and delete the record. We are reading using Executor Service with thread pool size of 10. Now my problem is each thread can read only one unique record. Suppose I have 10 threads and 10 records in DB. So that the thread 1 can read one record and the other thread can read a different record. Can we do this in Spring Data without using any synchronization?

Answer (score 1):

Simple short answer no. You have to do some synchronization either on application side or on the database level.